# Does $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}+V\neq L)$?

Tags: set-theory

Does $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow  \operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}+V\neq L)$?

I know that by forcing over a transitive model we have $\mathsf{ZFC} \vdash \operatorname{Con} ( \mathsf{ZFC} + \mathsf{SM} ) \rightarrow \operatorname{Con} ( \mathsf{ZFC} + V \neq L )$, where $\mathsf{SM}$ denotes the statement that there is a standard model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. But does $\mathsf{ZFC}$ also prove the relative consistency statement above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZFC proves the *completeness theorem* - that if $T$ is a consistent theory, it has a model. ZFC also proves the *Lowenheim-Skolem theorem* - that any structure in a countable language has a countable elementary substructure.

Finally, one last point: ZFC proves that forcing "works" (in the sense that generic filters and extensions exist, and that the forcing theorems hold) over countable models of ZFC, *even if those models are ill-founded*.

*This requires doing a bit more work in the basic development of forcing, but fundamentally not that much: given a countable $M$ and a $P\in M$ such that $M$ thinks "$P$ is a partial order," we have that $P$ (or rather, its translate $P\cap M$) really **is** a partial order; so we can talk about $P$-generic filters over $M$. Since $M$ is countable, such a filter (call it "$G$") exists. Now, the class of names can be defined in $M$ as usual, and the forcing extension $M[G]$ has as objects equivalence classes of names in $M$, with the equivalence relation coming from the definable forcing relation inside $M$ - even though names may be ill-founded, everything winds up checking out correctly.*

Now we reason in ZFC. If ZFC were consistent, it would have (by Completeness and Lowenheim-Skolem) a countable model $M$. This, in turn, means we get a countable model $M[G]$ of ZFC+V$\not=$L as usual.

---

Incidentally, ZFC is a **absolutely terrible** upper bound: much less than ZFC, even less than PA, suffices to prove $Con(ZFC)\implies Con(ZFC+V\not=L)$. This requires us to do some serious work, though.

Comment: Interesting,then you can make forcing from any countable model.

Comment: You identify two names x,y in M iff there is a condition $p\in G$ such that p force $x=y$ and M[G] is the quotient space,it isn't?

Comment: @Noah I'm just learning somewhat more about forcing and I didn't know about this "approach". Like you said, $\textbf{ZFC}$ is overkill, but still of interest since most mathematicians would assume ambient $\textbf{ZFC}$ either way. Could you expand on how this is achieved? I'm not quite following your argument, mostly because I don't know what absoluteness results we have for non-transitive models. Also, my definition of $M[G]$ does not involve the forcing relation; and for ctms of $\textbf{ZF-P}$ being a $P$-name is absolute, but how do we go about this in the forcing approach you described?

Comment: @Noah Maybe I should ask a new question about this... let me know.

Comment: @Jori I think you should ask a new question about this. Roughly speaking, though, the issue is this: with a ctm - the key point being "transitive" - we can define $M[G]$ by recursion. However, if $M$ is countable but ill-founded, that recursion doesn't make sense. Instead, we use the formulas which in the ctm case define forcing as our starting point here. When we do this carefully, *everything* carries over appropriately (for example, $M$ and $M[G]$ will satisfy the same $\Pi^1_2$ sentences).